# Elasticsearch error to start service

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, java-8, logstash, java-7

I have problems starting elasticsearch, the command to start is:

`cd /etc/init.d && ./elasticsearch start`

Out put.

```
/opt/jdk1.8.0_77 uno
JAVA /opt/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/java
Starting elasticsearch:                                    [  OK  ]
```

but executed status I get: "*elasticsearch dead but subsys locked*"

I tried deleting "elasticsearch", in /var/lock/subsys but, this file is generated again.

In the log says.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Java version: 1.7.0_40 suffers from critical bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8024830 which can cause data corruption.
Please upgrade the JVM, see http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_installation.html for current recommendations.
If you absolutely cannot upgrade, please add -XX:-UseSuperWord to the JVM_OPTS environment variable.
Upgrading is preferred, this workaround will result in degraded performance.
```

But the process is started with java 8,

```
elasticsearch      26918  0.8  1.0 30526952 724324 ?     Sl   Jul03   1:29 /opt/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Delasticsearch -Des.foreground=yes -Des.path.home=/opt/elasticsearch -cp :/opt/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-1.7.0.jar:/opt/elasticsearch/lib/*:/opt/elasticsearch/lib/sigar/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does it output using ''ps -ef|grep elasticsearch'' command?

Comment: elasticsearch 26918     1  0 Jul03 ?        00:03:52 /opt/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Delasticsearch -Des.foreground=yes -Des.path.home=/opt/elasticsearch -cp :/opt/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-1.7.0.jar:/opt/elasticsearch/lib/*:/opt/elasticsearch/lib/sigar/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

Verify java selection

> alternatives --config java

Make sure java 8 is in use. Elasticsearch requires at least Java 8.

**Please try setting up the variables in /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:**

> path.data: path/to/data
>
> path.work: path/to/work
>
> path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
>
> path.conf: /etc/elasticsearch

**Note: Give access to user "elasticsearch" for folder that
elasticsearch uses:**

chown -R elasticsearch /path/to/data
chown -R elasticsearch /path/to/work